# php - Meaning " \\1" in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, text, preg-replace

I have code to separate text with punctuation.

```
$text = "I was eating at a restaurant.";
echo $text . "<br>";
$token = preg_replace('/([\.\,\(\)\'\"\!\?\:\;])/', " \\1", $text);
echo $token;
```

And the output like this

> I was eating at a restaurant.
>
> I was eating at a restaurant .

I want to ask, What is the meaning **" \\1"** in that replacement?
I am still confused.

Can someone explain it?

Comment: Whatever is in first capturing group `(...)`.

Comment: [Ruby regex what does the \1 mean for gsub](//stackoverflow.com/q/15825872), [What's the meaning of a number after a backslash in a regular expression?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8624345) and [python regular expression "\1"](//stackoverflow.com/q/20802056)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is referencing your capturing group(s) `(...)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split text, you can use [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

`\\1` mean, that you call to first capturing group - Simply first sentence in middle of `(` and `)`.

If you have `" \\1"`, you will see that it find `"."` and replace it with `" ."` - with dot with additional space before dot.